# A variable from Class definition has been permanent stored (python class)

Tags: python, class

```
class intSet(object):

    def __init__(self):
        """Create an empty set of integers"""
        self.vals = []

    def insert(self, e):
        """Assumes e is an integer and inserts e into self""" 
        if not e in self.vals:
            self.vals.append(e)

    def __str__(self):
        """Returns a string representation of self"""
        self.vals.sort()
        return '{' + ','.join([str(e) for e in self.vals]) + '}'

    def intersect(self,other):
        """Define an intersect method that returns a new intSet
        containing elements that appear in both sets. """
        newset = intSet()
        for i in self.vals:
            for j in other.vals:
                if i==j:
                    newset.insert(j)
        return newset
```

After defining class below, I want to test it out. But because previously I tested s1.intersect(s3) , I seemed to have s1.intersect() stored as EmptyError permanently. I keep getting the same result with any s1.intersect() callout(like shown below). What could I have done that made "EmptyError" associated with s1.intersect method?  (I think I initially used "try and except: print("EmptyError") in my first version of the code.)

I am new to OOP and python and trying to get a better understanding of the class by these practices.

```
print(s1)
{1,2,3}

print(s5)
{2,3}

print(s1.intersect(s5))
EmptyError
None
```

I didn't save my first version `def intersect`. This is how I would remember it.

```
def intersect(self,other):
    """Define an intersect method that returns a new intSet
    containing elements that appear in both sets. """
    try:newset = intSet()
        for i in self.vals:
            for j in other.vals:
                if i==j:
                    newset.insert(j)
        return newset
    except:
        print("EmptyError")
```

Then I ran in the concole

```
s1 = intSet()
s1.insert(1)
s1.insert(2)
print(s1)
s2 = intSet()
s2.insert(2)
s2.insert(4)
print(s2)
s3 = s1.intersect(s2)
print(s3)
```

....output this

```
{1,2}
{2,4}
EmptyError
None
```

since then, `EmptyError` is always associated `s1.intersect()` callout. Even after I modify my class definition, changed new variable name for the method of intersect. `EmptyError`just won't go away from s1.intersect(anything).

Comment: Your sample code does not contain `EmptyError` anywhere.  If you're seeing it in your output, then you must be running some other code.

Comment: In `intersect()`, wouldn't it be a lot simpler to say `if i in other.vals` instead of explicitly looping over each value in other.vals?

Comment: I recalled my first version code which explains where "EmptyError" came from in my edit. Yes, it would be much simpler with `if i in other.vals`.

Comment: Yes, I saw your mention of the earlier version.  But `EmptyError` isn't in _this_ version of the code, therefore _this isn't the code you're running_.  Maybe you've got a similarly-named file that you're running mistakenly?  Or a stray `.pyc` file hanging around?